# React Page contents are not rendering in React (With Redux) without a manual refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I am new to React and currently doing a demo project in React - with Redux. I have designed a Homepage, But it's contents are not rendering on initial loading. The contents are loading perfectly after manually refreshing the page.

This is my UNSAFE_ComponentWillMount in Home.js

```
 export class Home extends Component {

 componentDidMount() {
  const id =this.props.userinfo.id
   axios.get(`http://localhost:8081/api/accounts/check/${id}`,id)
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response)
    if(response.status === 404){
      window.location.assign('/activate')
    }
  })
  .catch(err =>{
    console.log(err)
    window.location.assign('/activate')
  })
  this.props.initalAccountState(id)
  this.props.getBudgetsApi(id)
 }
.........
........
........
    const mapStateToProps = (state) =>{
      return{
        userinfo: state.user.user,
        accountinfo : state.account.accountDetails,
        checkAccount : state.account.checkAccount,
        isvalid:state.account.isvalid,
        budgetinfo:state.budget.budgetsinfo
        
      }
    }
    
    
    export default connect(mapStateToProps,{initalAccountState, checkAccountActivationApi,getBudgetsApi})(Home)
```

I replaced the UNSAFE_ComponentWillMount with ComponentDidMount and tried, but it not solved my problem.

This is the function in Redux Action to perform an API call to fetch the details.

```
//Api call for inital fetching of  Account details
export const initalAccountState =(id)=>{
    return (dispatch) =>{
        axios.get(`http://localhost:8081/api/accounts/getdetails/${id}`,id)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            dispatch(getAccountDetails(response.data))
            
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
}
```

This is my Router.js

```
 <Routes>
              {/* Protected Routes */}
              <Route element={<PrivateRoutes/>}>
                <Route path='/expenses' element={<Expenses/>} />
                <Route path="/home" element={<Home></Home>}></Route>
<Routes>
```

How Can I solve this Problem?
Please help me..

Comment: Have you added  a use effect to load the component initially?

Comment: `Home` isn't passed any props that we can see, so `this.props.userinfo` is undefined. I'm sure there are some errors in the console you should check for. `componentDidMount` is the correct lifecycle method to use when loading data. Please [edit] your post to include a more complete [mcve] between the app and router, and the components you are trying render on routes.

Comment: @SnehilAgrahari No, I am not using Hooks here.

Comment: @DrewReese I am using Redux . The  `userinfo` is a redux store value and I am accessing that through the `connect` method in `react-redux`  . The Redux store values can be seen in `mapSatateToProps` method

Also, if I manually referesh the page in browser, then the contents will render perfectly

Comment: Ok. So what *exactly* isn't rendering correctly until a page reload? Why would that be any different than the initial app mounting & rendering? Are there some other reproduction steps you've neglected to mention? What are the complete reproduction steps? What is attempted to be rendered? The code snippet still appears to be incomplete.

Comment: @DrewReese Thank You very much For your help. 

I got the solution I provided `async` and `await` to the `componentDidMount` . and it Worked.

Comment: Strange that would fix anything since the code in `componentDidMount` was already using a Promise-chain. Glad you sorted it out though.